# Comment Count for each Comment Author

Tags: comments, count

In WordPress 3.4.1:
I am trying to add the Comment Author's total number of comments beside their info. (name + date/time) in the comment's list.

Here is the SQL that I am using:

```
$count = $wpdb->get_var('SELECT COUNT(comment_ID) FROM '. $wpdb->comments. ' WHERE comment_author_email = "' . get_comment_author_email() .'" ' AND comment_approved = '1' AND comment_type = '');
```

Basically The Author's email will be checked and the total number of comments will be displayed. But also I want only approved comments to be counted and also I don't want pingbacks/trackbacks to be counted. The above code is returning a syntax error and probably is wrong in terms of logic.
Any help is appreciated. thanks.

Comment: Change the singel quotas to double like this `AND comment_approved = "1" AND comment_type = ""` See my answer below.

Answer (score 5):

Place this in your functions.php theme file:

```
<?php
function ps_count_user_comments() {
    global $wpdb;
    $count = $wpdb->get_var(
    'SELECT COUNT(comment_ID) FROM ' . $wpdb->comments. ' 
    WHERE comment_author_email = "' . get_comment_author_email() . '" 
    AND comment_approved = "1" 
    AND comment_type IN ("comment", "")'
    );

    return $count . ' comments';
}
?>
```

This code will count the author comments and do NOT include Trackbacks/Pingbacks.

Then You print it like this:

```
<?php echo ps_count_user_comments(); ?>
```

You can try to run this in your SQL and change mail@example.com to your mail. I assume your database prefix is wp_ but if its not, just change `wp_comments` to your prefix.

```
SELECT COUNT(comment_ID) FROM wp_comments 
WHERE comment_author_email = "mail@example.com"  
AND comment_approved = "1" 
AND comment_type IN ("comment", "")
```

Comment: Thanks Pontus. That's great. At least I was on the right track. One problem though: Trackbacks/pingbacks are still counted (all have same constant number), it seems that  comment_type = "" does not work even when I add 'comment' inside the quotes. How would I discriminate pingbacks/trackbacks from being counted?
 See image result with pingback counted as 13 (all pingbacks are some number): http://bacsoftwareconsulting.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/comment-counter-per-author.jpg
 Thanks for your help.

Comment: See my updated code, i have added `comment_type not in ("trackback","pingback")` so the SQL will look for all the comments that are Not in either trackback or pingback. Hope it works for you.

Comment: Thanks Pontus. Even though logically what you added in the code make sense. It still does not respond, I am still getting trackbacks/pingbacks counted (same as the image). Any other ideas? Probably I should enclose the code in an if statement to exclude trackbacks/pingbacks.

Comment: Okey, Can you try my updated code now? And if that not working can you update your question with some code where you adding the function?

Comment: It still counts pingbacks/trackbacks. I even tried to use the check_comment() function [http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/check_comment]  with no success. I think we should explore this function more in an if statement. I put the code in functions.php file and I edited the wp_list_comments() callback in functions.php so that it displays the comment count per author.
I Could not add the code due to max allowed characters here. But The code  is similar to what you have at the top. I tried all combinations of comment_type values. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in WordPress comment query for that. I also use [`get_comments();`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_comments/) for this feature on my template.

For the parameters, I simply use 3 parameters, the same as you want.

```
    $comail = get_comment_author_email();
    $args = array(
                'author_email' => $comail,
                'status'  => 'approve',
                'type'  => 'comment',
                );
```

[`wp_comment_query`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_comment_query/__construct/) is limitless. So anything is possible. Multiple comment-type is also supported with the `'type__in'` parameter.

Next, you can echo the `count($comments);`. You can also use `'count'=>'true'`, parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Bikran solutions can also uses as function, so you can use in several places at your theme. Also, I think he's code is needing an extra line before `count($comments)`:

```
$comments = get_comments( $args );
```

So the ready-to-use function would be:

```
function my_count_comments($comail){
    $args = array(
                'author_email' => $comail,
                'status'  => 'approve',
                'type'  => 'comment',
                );
    $comments = get_comments( $args );
    return count($comments);
}
```

And uses:

```
echo my_count_comments(get_comment_author_email());
```