# Get total number of comment of the posts written by an author

Tags: plugins, php, database, comments, author

I have put this code on author.php page

```
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 

 //gets the number of comment(s) on a post                  
 $comments_number = get_comments_number();

 //adds all the comment counts up
 $numbercomment += $comments_number;

 ?>
 <?php endwhile; ?>

 <span>A total of <?php echo $numbercomment; ?> comments have been made on this author posts.</span>
```

Currently i am using a loop to find number of a comments on a post and total it with all the other comment count on other posts. The consists of only the author's post so in that way i can find the number of comments people have made on that specific author's posts.
Is there a simpler way of doing it.

EDIT:
I want to count the total number of comments people have made on all of that author's posts. 
Put the above code up in author.php file and you will get what i mean..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comment Count for each Comment Author](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/57370/comment-count-for-each-comment-author)

Comment: @bueltge I want to count the comments people have made on that author's total posts

Comment: OK, really different. Your Edit is helpful for this goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `get_comments()`, this way you don't have to loop through posts.

```
<?php
    $args = array(
        'post_author' => '' // fill in post author ID
    );

    $author_comments = get_comments($args);

    echo count($author_comments);

?>
```

Comment: I want to count the total number of comments people have made on all of that author's posts

Comment: Yes, that's what the code is supposed to do.

Comment: Sorry my bad didn't check it..

Answer (score 2):

Here I've written a SQL based function for you-

```
function the_dramatist_count_user_comments( $args = array() ) {
    global $wpdb;
    $default_args = array(
        'author_id' => 1,
        'approved' => 1
    );
    $param = wp_parse_args( $args, $default_args );
    $sql = $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(comments.comment_ID) 
            FROM {$wpdb->comments} AS comments 
            LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->posts} AS posts
            ON comments.comment_post_ID = posts.ID
            WHERE posts.post_author = %d
            AND comment_approved = %d
            AND comment_type IN ('comment', '')",
        $param
    );

    return $wpdb->get_var( $sql );
}
```

Use it like below-

```
$author_posts_comments_count = the_dramatist_count_user_comments(
    array(
        'author_id' => 1, // Author ID
        'approved' => 1, // Approved or not Approved
    )
);
```

Now on `$author_posts_comments_count` you'll get the full comments count for an authors all posts.

> It's tested.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I want to count the total number of comments people have made on all of that author's  posts

Comment: @MeghGandhi, Check the updated answer.

Comment: thanks you for your efforts.. But i would stick to using only php as i have forgotten sql XD